# Invariance of Clifford multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, group-actions, spin-geometry

I am checking some basic properties of Clifford multiplication while reading the book "Twistors and Killing spinors on Riemannian manifolds" by Baum et al. It is said that Clifford multiplication is *invariant* under the action of $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$, and this is where I am stuck.

Clifford multiplication is a particular product between a vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and a spinor $\varphi \in \Delta_n$, where $\Delta_n$ is the $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$-representation obtained by restriction of the standard representation $\rho$ of the Clifford algebra $Cl(\mathbb R^n) \otimes \mathbb C$. I should discuss a bit more carefully this point, but I do not think it will be relevant for my question (maybe I am wrong). By definition, viewing $x \in \mathbb R^n$ in $Cl(\mathbb R^n)$, we have $$x \cdot \varphi := \rho(x)\varphi.$$ Now $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ also acts on $\mathbb R^n$. In fact the map $\lambda\colon \mathrm{Spin}(n) \to \mathrm{SO}(n)$ such that $\lambda(u)x = uxu^{-1}$ is the double covering of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$, and here $x$ is again a vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

The problem now is to prove that Clifford multiplication is $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$-invariant, where $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ via $\lambda$ and on $\Delta_n$ via $\rho$. Given $u \in \mathrm{Spin}(n)$ this should amount to saying that $\lambda(u)x \cdot \rho(u)\varphi = x\cdot \varphi$. However, what I get is
\begin{align*}
\lambda(u)x \cdot \rho(u)\varphi & = uxu^{-1}\cdot \rho(u)\varphi \\
& = \rho(uxu^{-1})\rho(u)\varphi \\
& = \rho(uxu^{-1}u)\varphi \\
& = \rho(ux)\varphi \\
& = \rho(u)\rho(x)\varphi = \rho(u)x \cdot \varphi.
\end{align*}
This seems to prove that Clifford multiplication is $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$-*equivariant*, not invariant. Does anybody see where I am wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right. People are often sloppily using "invariant" for "equivariant", and this seems to be one of these cases.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for the comment. In my view some parts of the book are not really formal, the authors skip a lot of the general theory to get quickly to the applications (which is what I need). So I am incline to believe you are right.

Comment: Clifford algebras seem to be a magnet for sloppiness and lack of rigor. Maybe it's because of the applications, but even mathematicians skimp more often than usually in that field.